# Para que serve o evento abort?

Tags: javascript

Não encontrei nenhuma referência explicando na prática para que serve esse evento (`abort`), que nem no exemplo abaixo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="video/test.mp4" controls></video>
    
    <script>
        let video = document.querySelector("video");
        
        video.onabort = () => {
            alert("Aborted");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando vai ser disparado o evento `abort`? o [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onabort.asp) define esse evento como:

> O evento onabort ocorre quando o usuário interrompe o carregamento de um elemento

Como assim interromper o carregamento do elemento? alguém me explica como funciona esse evento e se possível um exemplo.

Comment: Não amigo! queria um exemplo do evento ocorrendo e sendo executado algo quando o mesmo ocorrer

Comment: O funcionamento do elemento, você mesmo descreveu na sua própria pergunta. Tem também a resposta indicada pelo @Icaro Martins. E a coisa toda é bem trivial. O que aparentemente você quer saber é como o usuário pode interromper o carregamento de um elemento, e a principal maneira é bastante simples também: clicando no botão x que geralmente fica perto das setas e do botão de recarregar.